# Search for single post by 2 tags

Tags: php, wp-query, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

i have "Tag1" and "Tag2" i want to find most recent post with both tags.So far i have tried this, i know im close, but it is listing all posts containing either tag.

```
$args = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy'         => 'post_tag',
            'terms'            => 'agirt',
            'field'            => 'slug',
            'operator'         => 'AND'.
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy'         => 'post_tag',
            'terms'            => 'fetch',
            'field'            => 'slug',
        ),
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $html = '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $post_title = $the_query->post->post_title; 
            echo "<li>$post_title</li>";
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
        echo $html;
    }
```

Comment: $query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag' => 'agirt+fetch' ) ); ended up working for me as well, just wanted to post this here as an alternate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `tax_query` param in your args (and replacing the dot with a comma) should get you what you're looking for:

```
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'fetch',
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'agirt',
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, ive been trying to make this work for like 5 days(I'm basically just a script kiddy). I truly appreciate your time and effort, and the knowledge you have aquired.

Comment: I tried to give you reputation but im too new to this forum

Comment: No worries man, glad it worked for you!  :)